# Peculiar pictures in advanced maths books

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, big-list

I have recently started reading *Introduction to Symplectic Topology* by McDuff and Salamon and I came across this picture:
[image: Symplectic camel]

I find it very funny and really interesting. I read on Wikipedia that Ian Stewart had come with this expression when discussing about the non-squeezing theorem in an article in *Nature*. But *Introduction to Symplectic Topology* is an advanced book on symplectic topology and not a maths popularization book so I found it quite odd.

Then I remembered I saw another curious picture:
[image]

which is taken from Bredon's *Topology and Geometry*.

My question is: does anyone know any other peculiar images from advanced maths books that illustrate some mathematical concept?

Comment: A T Fomenko has contributed some very peculiar drawings to maths books, for instance Koblitz's book on modular forms.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown: Here's a Fomenko-inspired animation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JXtu5M8kB6w

Comment: @HansLundmark: When I click on that link, YouTube tells me the video is "private".

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg: Same for me now (it wasn't private when I posted that comment)... But I found another copy: https://vk.com/video1272347_149789273

Answer (score 6):

V.I. Arnold likes to use cats for their illustrations when explaining higher-level actions with transformations.
In their book "[Mathematical Methods of Classical Mechanics](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Mathematical_Methods_of_Classical_Mechan/5OQlBQAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0)", there are these images:

[image: 2]
[image: 3]

Or these images from their book "[Ergodic problems of classical mechanics](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Ergodic_Problems_of_Classical_Mechanics/9TxhQgAACAAJ?hl=en)":

[image: 5]
[image: 6]

Their liking for images of cats used to describe things in their works is what created this: [Arnold's cat map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arnold%27s_cat_map). On that page, there is this figure for the Discrete Cat Map:

[image: 8]

---

In W.W. Sawyer's book [Mathematician's Delight](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Mathematician_s_Delight/TNE6AwAAQBAJ?hl=en), in the Chapter "From Speed to Curves" where it's talked about the applications of the second derivative, it has one of my all-time favorite images of a stickperson:

[image: 10]